# Is it OK to create duplicate questions as aliases for more search hits?

Tags: discussion

A question can be asked in many different ways. Is it OK to create a question for almost every way of asking that question and then mark it as a duplicate of a canonical question?

Why I'm asking is because it would be great to always get a good Stack Overflow result for whatever query I might type at Google.

Comment: If you mean you want to ask questions only to have them closed as duplicates of others, then no, thanks.

Comment: Ref: [How to check if two strings are the same in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23483399) (10K+ only)

Comment: Do note that while you might have done it with the best of intentions, simply googling for "[*compare strings c#*](https://www.google.com/search?q=compare+strings+c%23)" (which is the subject in question) will show you 4 different MSDN resources first with 3 Stack Overflow resources next. I think this is more than enough.

Comment: Did you consider creating a word press site with all the various combinations and then linking into SO from there?

Comment: Claim: there are an infinite ways to present the same question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Creating "Alias" questions isn't a good idea. Let me explain why.

The *motivation* to create these questions isn't wrong at all! Many things are asked in a way that make you go, "I would *never* have found this in a search!" The thought of creating a better pointer for future Googlers is completely understandable.

However, on Stack Exchange, this is generally done organically. When someone *actually asks the question in their own way*, that question then gets closed as a duplicate, creating a "naturally grown" pointer.

This generally works fine - and when it doesn't, that's owed to there being *more duplicates than the people closing the questions can handle.* That's why artificially creating *even more duplicates* is generally frowned upon, as is witnessed by Frédéric Hamidi's comment above.